# Create Facebook applications for a company without a personal profile

Tags: facebook

We want to create a Facebook application but do not want that application to be associated with a personal account. Is that possible? Is it possible to create a Business account using the company name, do not attach a personal account to it and create an application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic]."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Facebook applications must have developers and these are can't be companies so you can't do it if your company don't have facebook developer account.

All you can do is open facebook developers for company accounts and then you can create applications.