# How do I/Can I create a Facebook app for my company without using my personal Facebook account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-oauth

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525556/create-facebook-applications-for-a-company-without-a-personal-profile), but I'm writing from a developer's perspective rather than the company's.

I prefer to keep my personal and professional lives separate, and thus would like to be able to create Facebook apps not tied to my personal FB account.  Per FB policies, each account must be associated to a real person, i.e. I can't have a separate developer account.  Is there a way to create FB apps without using my personal account?  Do you other freelancers (or even non-freelancers) just use your personal accounts?  If so, do you have any qualms about doing this?  If I'm going to be collaborating with other developers, do I need to worry about sharing any personal information with them?

Thanks.

Comment: I am using my personal account(because I didn't hear about any other solution, as you are asking) and I have no problems with it. If there is someone that does not appeal to me in regard to something that I am doing I just remove that persons ability to view that "something"(Privacy settings/publish control). Good luck.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating and managing a Facebook app from a Business Account](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10805745/creating-and-managing-a-facebook-app-from-a-business-account)

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic]."

Comment: I am currently fighting this issue, I've tried making other accounts, with other emails and company phone numbers, which worked. But then I made a mistake when configuring my app and my account gets blocked for potential malicious behavior; so I'm glad I didn't use my personal account, but Facebook knows my work IP now, and I'm having issues making new accounts.

Answer (score 7):

You can't create application without being authorized developer which require either providing Facebook with your **mobile phone** or **credit card**.

Answer to the question you stated as similar is perfectly fits here too...

As for the other developers that need to work on your app you can add them with role Developer/Beta Tester based on your needs (and not Admin) in [Developer Application](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) and carefully choosing only persons you trust have permissions to modify your application settings. Once Developers/Beta-Testers finish the work you should remove 'em.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a company account or another account is against [Facebook's term of service](https://www.facebook.com/terms.php):

> You will not provide any false personal information on Facebook, or
>   create an account for anyone other than yourself without permission.