# Can you use the Messenger API without having a page?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I would like to use the API's capabilities to send an attachment. After reading the documentation you have to have a page token to use it. Is there a workaround to this? Different approach? I am relatively new to this area so I will appreciate any comments

Comment: Messenger API is for communication between a user and a page only. There is no API for user-to-user messaging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, I do not think this is possible. Facebook states that this is a **requirement** in their [documentation page.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/app-setup)

> A Facebook Page will be used as the identity of your Messenger
> experience. When people chat with your app, they will see the Page
> name and the Page profile picture. To create a new Page, visit
> https://www.facebook.com/pages/create

Additionally, you will also need to make a facebook account by providing your mobile phone number or credit card. I recommend that you follow this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7829731/11759696) as well.